# Integration by parts, double integral and PDE

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, multiple-integral

I have a function $v=v(x,y,t)$ satisfying the following PDE (degerate heat equation)

$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} - \Delta_x v - \Delta_y v - 2 \nabla_x \cdot \nabla_y v = 0$.

I also have a function $r:[0,+\infty) \to [0,+\infty)$ such that $r(|x-y|)$ is of class $C^2$. The paper I am reading claims that using the PDE above and integration by parts, it is true that

$ \frac{d}{d t} \iint r(|x-y|) v(x,y,t) dx dy $

$= \iint v(x,y,t) \left(\Delta_x \left[ r (|x-y|) \right] + \Delta_y \left[ r (|x-y|) \right] + 2 \nabla_x \nabla_y [r(|x-y|)] \right) dx dy 
$

How can one show this?

Comment: Differentiate under the integral sign, replace $\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}$ by the rest of the PDE and then integrate by parts twice for every term you get.

Comment: You might need to argue why you won't get boundary terms, for this you probably need some decay for $r$.

Comment: Sure, you are right! Thank you very much!

Comment: I would suggest you write an answer :)